# Can I create a drop-down list (as opposed to a combo box)?

Tags: ms-access, drop-down-menu, ms-access-2007

Creating *combo boxes* in Access is easily enough.  However, *drop-down lists* are slightly easier for users when there's no need to edit or add values to the list.

Is there a property I can set to make a combo box control manifest as a drop-down list?  Is there a custom ActiveX control available with drop-down style?

Comment: A list box is a separate type of control.  It's a native control, so you don't need an ActiveX substitute.  Explore the available controls with your form in Design View.

Comment: Indeed, but what I want is a drop-down list.  Is there a way to make either a combo box or a list box behave as a drop-down list?

Comment: Does the combo box `Dropdown` method give you what you want?

Comment: As a workaround, that might help.  Based on your comments on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8840177/opposite-of-combo-box-dropdown-method, you're suggesting triggering `DropDown` in the `On Enter` event?  That's not quite as clean as an actual drop-down list, but it's simple to implement and gets me 90% of the way there!  Please add it as an answer, and unless someone tops you I'll accept it in a few days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See whether the combo box `.Dropdown` method gets you close to what you need.  I cribbed this example from the Access help topic:

```vba
Private Sub SupplierID_GotFocus()
    Me!SupplierID.Dropdown
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your phrase "manifest as a drop-down" correctly, I think you mean that you want to restrict the user to selecting from a set of pre-populated options only.

**Provide a List of Approved Values to Select**

For example, if you want them to select a Month, and there are only twelve valid entries Jan-Dec, you can provide a list of months from a query, table, or direct input into the Combo Box's Row Source property.

**Keep the User from Adding New Values or Editing Existing Values**

What I think you may mean by "manifesting as a List Box" is that you can also then restrict the user to only selecting from your provided values by setting the Limit to List property of the Combo Box to Yes. Setting this property will restrict your users to your list, and not allow edits or new list entries. Remember to take addition steps if you need to make sure the user has selected one of your list values.

**Use Dropdown and an Event like On Got Focus together**

The Dropdown method "opens" the list so that the user can see the available options. For example, you can set it to the control's On Got Focus Event property so that the user will see some or all available options when the focus is set to this control.

Best of luck!

Comment: Providing a restricted list is not the issue, rather I'd like to offer the specific UI of a drop-down list.  E.g., one click anywhere in the control expands the list.  The event-and-`Dropdown` method is a decent workaround, but using the actual control would be better, if that's possible.